# Sort Event in ZK

Tags: zk

I have added comparators for sorting in asc,desc order.

```
listHeader.setSortAscending(new MyComparator(true)); //True for asc
listHeader.setSortDescending(new MyComparator(false)); //False for asc
```

when I do this. `Events.postEvent(Events.ON_SORT,listHeader,null);` 
I get the listbox sorted in ascending order, but I want it to be sorted in descending order when I call above `Events.postEvent();` am I missing setting any attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer :) 
I had to set attribute Sort Direction to "ascending" `listHeader.setSortDirection("ascending");`